# Use case in a presentation

Tags: use-case

I have asked to prepare a presentation at college, which should have a use to reflect the outcome/innovation of my application. Should I include the use case diagram and then show the use case or just write only the use case?

My application suggests the best route to the user, from destination A to B. This includes public transport, car and walking. How do I depict this in my use case diagram? Are the car, public transport actor?

Comment: although use cases are software and system engineering tools, they are not really part of programming languages and you might get a better answer on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/use-case).

Comment: Also your first question sounds like something you should ask your professor (I've had to do a use case diagram & form for one class, only form for another) as we can't know what he or she wants.